# Need Line chart With Dynamic X axis Values and data

Tags: ios, dynamic, charts, line

I am working on iPhone applications.I Need Line chart With Dynamic X axis Values and data For showing temperature values in graph with scroll view enabled to scroll horizontally to view the further graph as the graph extends with time.

Y Axis Labels : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;
X Axis labels : date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, ...etc.
(Should increase dynamically for every 30 seconds)

Graph data is : Temperature on the x axis date (should increase dynamically with x axis)

The main Point is graph values should not submerge in same length, The graph should be extend out of screen and the user should be able to scroll horizontally to see the whole graph values.

thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://www.code4app.net/ios/Line-and-Bar-of-Chart,-you-can-mark-the-range-of-value-you-want,-and-show-the-ma/54b375c2e24741d5113a9686

Comment: @vaibby : Thanks for the reply. I tried that already. But the graph x axis and data should increase with time. So that the scroll view content size and line chart view size also should increase with time which I failed to do with the example

Answer (score 0):

I highly prefer below external library for the chart in iOS developement.

Which includes following types of graphs.

1. LineChart (with legend, simple design)
2. Combined-Chart (bar- and linechart in this case)
3. BarChart
4. BarChart (grouped DataSets)
5. Horizontal-BarChart
6. PieChart (with selection, ...)
7. ScatterChart
8. CandleStickChart
9. RadarChart

[Find the iOS Github library from here .](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts)

Comment: The library u mentioned shows how to draw colourful graphs with static data. But I need graphs with dynamic data and with dynamic content size.

Comment: You just pass the array of your data

Comment: By Passing the array of data we will refresh the graph with new data on the same content size. But I need data to be added to the existing data ..not to replace with new data..and content size to be added to existing content size.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but did you get any luck on this? I am also struggling about this. I keep my data in an array, and every time I want to update the chart I remove the current dataset and create a new one with my data array and feed that dataset to that chart. After that I do that. I do `self.data?.removeEntry(data.first!, dataSetIndex: 0)` and `self.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Note that `data` is the array that has my data.